# Areas of Focus: Cryptic Clues

Tags: riddle, cryptic-clues, letters

> What follows are fifteen standard cryptic clues to solve.  The catch is, I've removed the letter count from each clue.  To help you out, note the following:
>
> 1. No answers have the same number of letters
> 2. All answers are exactly one word
> 3. No answer has more than 15 letters
> 4. When all solutions are in order, a keyword will confirm the answers

---

**CLUES:**

- Brilliant South American empire's fall?
- Friendship is fifty bronies performing in horse-speak
- Wood steering wheel without front
- Unpleasantness from broken bones absorbing toxic solder lead
- Listless lauding listless
- Common radiation scatters in vacant terminal
- Odd pair creates something irrational?
- Clarifications reveal small imp prancing about is fictional
- Dancing otter holding a block
- Commitments for new dances around here
- Curves: Extreme!
- Almost secure a greenback?
- Charges in and makes speech
- Ardently laze about with lousy characters
- Small layer turns a beast

  ---

good luck!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The clues:

```
Brilliant South American empire's fall?
```

> INCANDESCENT (12)

```
Friendship is fifty bronies performing in horse-speak
```

> NEIGHBORLINESS (14)

```
Wood steering wheel without front
```

> ELM (3) though I was briefly distracted by (d)ASH

```
Unpleasantness from broken bones absorbing toxic solder lead
```

> OBNOXIOUSNESS (13)

```
Listless lauding listless
```

> LANGUID (7)

```
Common radiation scatters in vacant terminal
```

> TRADITIONAL (11)

```
Odd pair creates something irrational?
```

> PI (2)

```
Clarifications reveal small imp prancing about is fictional
```

> SIMPLIFICATIONS (15)

```
Dancing otter holding a block
```

> INGOT (5)

```
Commitments for new dances around here
```

> ADHERENCES (10)

```
Curves: Extreme!
```

> S (though I'm not 100% sure I understand it: I think "extreme" means "last letter of" and it's an &lit, though the definition then seems a little flaky to me)

```
Almost secure a greenback?
```

> CLAM (4) though I was briefly distracted by BUCK(le)

```
Charges in and makes speech
```

> INVOICES (8). I confess I only found this by asking a computer to list all words of the form IN-----S.

```
Ardently laze about with lousy characters
```

> ZEALOUSLY (9)

```
Small layer turns a beast
```

> ANIMAL (6). This one took me far, far too long.

Putting it together:

> In length order we have:
>  `S`
>  `PI`
>  `ELM`
>  `CLAM`
>  `INGOT`
>  `ANIMAL`
>  `LANGUID`
>  `INVOICES`
>  `ZEALOUSLY`
>  `ADHERENCES`
>  `TRADITIONAL`
>  `INCANDESCENT`
>  `OBNOXIOUSNESS`
>  `NEIGHBORLINESS`
>  `SIMPLIFICATIONS`
>  whose first letters yield SPECIALIZATIONS, fitting nicely with the title.

Comment: This is all exactly right!  Excellent work.  For the one that took too long, I was unsure about including it at first, since the word you reverse isn't exactly common.  And, for the one letter clue... yeah, a bit iffy for sure, but I was indeed going for an &lit, and you were able to put it together.  Nice solves!

Comment: I said it took me "too long" because I felt I should have spotted it sooner. I'm familiar with the word in question and had noticed the reversal myself in the past. Ah well, human brains are known to be a bit rubbish :-).

Comment: The puzzle was fun, by the way,

Comment: Yes, that was a fun puzzle. (Couldn't solve the 4-letter one, but fortunately, Gareth's answer was already there.)